# jfreechart overlay two charts on top of other

Tags: java, jfreechart

My problem is: I wanna create a PNG that has a an image of a small circle above an xy chart. My circle is kind of a pie chart so I can display it as pie chart, and I want to be able to put it in any (x,y) in the graph i want.
I thought about XYShapeAnnotation but the circle needs to be divided to parts and I don't want to do it with java graphics since I don't know it, and I don't think I need it for my needs.
It is important to note that I cannot use JfreeChart overlaying method since I have two different Datasets (XY,Pie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XYDrawableAnnotation` to place the smaller chart.

Comment: the pie is displayed on top, but it is not transparent, I've tried `setBackgroudAlpha(0.0) / setBackgroundImageAlpha(0.0)` but it doesn't work. edit: I've did it on the plot and on the chart and now iw works, together with `setBackgroundPaint(null)`